# Parse DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, type-conversion

I am trying to parse a TimeString that looks like:

```
11/Apr/2014:00:00:12 +0200
```

my code looks like

```
DateTime.ParseExact("11/Apr/2014:00:00:12 +0200", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss zzz", null)
```

I looked at [the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx) and it looks good for me but I have no clue why I always get a FormatException.

Comment: Please check this http://dotnetfiddle.net/zIv6Sv. It seems that it works.

Comment: You might want to pass in a specific CultureInfo parameter, as `Apr` is not applicable to a lot of locales

Comment: Since your string contains an offset, you might be better off parsing it to a `DateTimeOffset` instead of a `DateTime`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the `InvariantCulture` as a format provider.

```
var d = DateTime.ParseExact("11/Apr/2014:00:00:12 +0200", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Your format string is considering that the `/` and `:` characters are specific format separators that will resolve to the ones defined in your current culture, just as HH would signify "hours" in your format. Please refer to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) to see that the [time separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#timeSeparator) and [date separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) are predefined and will be replaced by the culture specific values.

It is possible to [escape the special characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#escape) but I think that in the long run your code will be much safer with the `InvariantCulture`